# how to make histogram from all data from data.frame in single chart in R

Tags: r, histogram

i have a data.frame with multiple columns of data. I would like to generate a single histogram of all data independent of the column, as I would like to know how the frequencies of this data.frame are distributed.

For example:

i have the data.frame with columns x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5

```
set.seed(9)
x1<-rnorm(20,5,1.09)
x2<-rnorm(20,5,0.80)
x3<-rnorm(20,5,0.50)
x4<-rnorm(20,5,0.02)
x5<-rnorm(20,5,0.15)
df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)

df
```

I try  the library(Hmisc) with comand:

```
hist.data.frame(df)
```

but generated a histogram for each column. I did not want this.

[image]

Comment: `hist(unlist(df, use.names = FALSE))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unlist` before using `hist` to *make a histogram from all data from a `data.frame`.*

```
hist(unlist(df))
```

Comment: the `unlist` command would convert the entire data.frame to a `vector`, correct?

Comment: Yes. `?unlist` gives: *... simplifies it to produce a vector which contains all the atomic components which occur ...*